# Is there a good way to make a remote machine dual-bootable into Windows and Linux?

Tags: grub, multi-boot

I'd like to make a dual-boot machine that can be rebooted into either OS *remotely*.

The only idea I have is to make the grub configuration live on a FAT partition so that it can be edited by either OS. The user would manually change the default OS in menu.lst. (Maybe this would only work with grub 1, but I think that's all that's in CentOS right now.)

Will this work, or is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: Does anyone know why this might be getting votes to close?

Comment: Thanks, @Zoredache. I just flagged myself. I saw it as a server problem because the machine is remote and used by multiple people, but because the decision of booting will be made out-of-band, you're right that it's more of a remote workstation.

Comment: I think grub-reboot is a much simpler way than any of the ones below. see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/661512/how-to-remotely-control-which-os-grub-boots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the system can boot from its network card, and if you have an accessible DHCP server you can remotely configure:

- Make separate partitions for Linux and Windows (practically goes without saying, but just in case).
- Configure the DHCP server to offer a
  Linux PXE boot that mounts the Linux
  root filesystem when you want Linux,
  and to offer nothing at all when you
  want Windows.
- Configure the dual-boot system's boot order to
  try the NIC first, and if it can't
  boot from the NIC, it falls back to
  the internal hard drive.

That's what we do to have one set of PCs be a regular Windows lab during the day and evenings, and be a small Linux cluster overnights and on weekends.

Answer (score 3):

If any of these OS is a *Windows* one, make it bootable by default.

Install **[iReboot](http://neosmart.net/iReboot/)** (*NeoSmart Technologies*) on it, possibly along with **[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)** *(same vendor, both are free for non-commercial)* for better tweaking boot configurations.

*iReboot* allows you to reboot your computer on any other OS on the same computer from the opened Windows session on which it is running without getting through the OS menu selection.

[image: *iReboot screenshot*]

Of course you will have to boot first into this *Windows* session before taking control of it for rebooting elsewhere if this session was not the one you wanted to boot in.

*iReboot* adds an icon into the notification ("systray") area which opens a popup menu including all OS names defined at the BCD level, you just have to select one of them for rebooting directly on it.

I currently use this solution for remote dual booting between *Windows 10* and *Linux Debian*, but I had to use *EasyBCD* before for creating a dual boot between these two OS.

Comment: Answers, especially high-quality answers know no time limit. However, you don't need to explicitly signal this in your answer, folks might perceive that as noise :-) Could you elaborate a bit more on iReboot perhaps? Maybe a link to it, a screenshot and a bit more about what it does? Makes your answer more likely to attract upvotes!

Comment: It happened previously that I answer to an old question and I got a weird comment on this, I just wanted to prevent it. :-) I edited my answer for adding links, more comments and a picture _(just a copy of the one provided on the official site, this is far less complicated than making my own one)_.

Comment: iReboot does not seem to pick up anything linux (or grub) related for me...

Answer (score 1):

How about a single-port, IP-based KVM.  When you need to reboot, connect to the KVM, restart and select your boot option?  I like it because it is not complicated to set up.

If it is an HP server you could use the ILO for this.  Other servers have similar tools.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution, but it should work: install Windows on the first partition with the default configuration, install Linux in the second one *and put its boot loader in the partition's boot sector (instead of overwriting the MBR)*, then from each O.S. you can change the active partition on the disk (using `diskpart` in Windows and `fdisk` in Linux) and reboot the computer, thus forcing the next boot into the other one.

With this solution, you will not have any boot menu to select the O.S. you want to boot; but if you only need to change this setting remotely, this should not be a problem (and you can of course change the active partition from inside any O.S., you just need for it to finish booting if you're just starting the computer and want to boot the one that is currently not active).

Answer (score 0):

What OS is currently on the machines in question?

If it's Windows, my first instinct would be to use Norton Ghost. There is an agent that comes with some of the later versions that you can install on a machine to remotely image it, provided that there is infrastructure in place on the machine's network to serve the image files.

The main issue with this is that you'd overwrite the Windows OS that is currently on the machine.

Comment: afaik Norton Ghost will only allow to build the machine (remotely) but won't allow to select which OS to boot remotely.

Comment: The initial settings would be in the grub configuration, pre-imaging.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would prefer booting in one OS and installing the other (less used one) in a virtual machine so it can be started after boot.

I'm not convinced changing grub frequently is a very easy or secure solution, mainly remotely. Anyways, when grub updates to 2 this will not work anymore I think.

Comment: Both operating systems need to connect to a special PCI card that cannot be emulated.